# How to "highlight" a word found in a text file?

Tags: python

I am searching a text file for a word. It finds the word and returns the line that has the word. This is good, but I would like to highlight or make the word bold in that line.

Can I do this in Python? Also I could use a better way to get the users txt file path.

```
def read_file(file):
    #reads in the file and print the lines that have searched word. 
    file_name = raw_input("Enter the .txt file path: ")
    with open(file_name) as f:
        the_word = raw_input("Enter the word you are searching for: ")
        print ""
        for line in f:
            if the_word in line:
                print line
```

Comment: What do you mean highlight the line? Do you mean save a new file with that line highlighted? Print it highlighted? Open a text editor with it highlighted? Something else? I'm guessing you meant save a new file with that line highlighted, but then it depends on what file format you want to save it as. .rtf? .html? .doc? Something else?

Comment: I see sorry save the file to .txt and highlight just the word that was searched for.

Comment: .txt is for plain text with no highliting.

Comment: Either the answer is "you can't" or the question is too broad. Please refine.

Answer (score 16):

**Note**: This will work only in the console.  You cannot color text in a plaintext file.  That is why it is called *plain*text.

One format for special characters is `\033[(NUMBER)(NUMBER);(NUMBER)(NUMBER);...m`

The first number can be 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4.  For colors, we use only 3 and 4.  3 means foreground color, and 4 means background color.  The second number is the color:

```
0 black
1 red
2 green
3 yellow
4 blue
5 magenta
6 cyan
7 white
9 default
```

Therefore, to print "Hello World!" with a blue background and a yellow foreground, we could do the following:

```
print("\033[44;33mHello World!\033[m")
```

Whenever you start a color, you will want to reset to the defaults.  That is what `\033[m` does.

Comment: Considering the comments below the question, you should precise that this will provide colored output in the console (provided the terminal supports it).

Comment: @ColinPitrat: Thanks.  I changed it.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you mean by highlight is printing the text with a different color. You can not save text with a different color (unless you be using html or something like that)

With the answer provided by @zondo you should get some code like this (python3)

```
import os

file_path = input("Enter the file path: ")

while not os.path.exists(file_path):
    file_path = input("The path does not exists, enter again the file path: ")


with open(file_path, mode='rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()


search_word = input("Enter the word you want to search:")

if search_word in text:
    print()
    print(text.replace(search_word, '\033[44;33m{}\033[m'.format(search_word)))
else:
    print("The word is not in the text")
```

---

An example of using html, would be:

```
if search_word in text:
    with open(file_path+'.html', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text.replace(search_word, '<span style="color: red">{}</span>'.format(search_word)))
else:
    print("The word is not in the text")
```

Then a file ending with `.html` will be created and you can open it with your navigator. Your word will be highlighted in red! (That's a really basic code)

happy hacking

Comment: I used the first code, But as I use **shell**,It doesn t work.What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pythons [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method for this problem:

```
#Read in the a file
with file = open('file.txt', 'r') :
    filedata = file.read()

#Replace 'the_word' with * 'the_word' * -> "highlight" it
filedata.replace(the_word,  "*" + the_word + '*')

#Write the file back
with file = open('file.txt', 'w') :
    file.write(filedata)`
```